# Can not find MediaPlayer.create(Context context, int resid) method from WordAdapter class

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-context

Trying to use *WordAdapter.this* as a Context doesn't get accepted by the compiler in the following code:

```
playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(WordAdapter.this, currentWord.getAudioResourceId());
                mp.start();
            }
        });
```

The class is WordAdapter, and it extends ArrayAdapter using a collection of Word objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MediaPlayer.create() needs a `Context` as first parameter. You can pass an context to it. 
Your adapter class is not child of Context class so you can not pass `WordAdapter.this` as an context.

Comment: Since using only `this` didn't work either, I tried with `getContext()` and it works now. Thank you!

Comment: Dude how can this work. which return you current class reference. I just told you way to do this. It is your class where you are doing code. You will know where is your context.

Comment: You can use this in your activity class. or an class which extends Context class.

Comment: May be you are working in dialog or fragment. where getContext() returns its activity context

Comment: I  hope it helped you. You can mark this answer right to appreciate me.